# Subdivision modifer selected surface not hiding until turned of in viewport

Tags: subdivision-surface

I don't know if this is intended on Blender 3.1.2, but I am working on a model and when I try to hide with the sub-surf modifier on it doesn't hide the surface. The vertices no longer select-able but still visible in the view port. The vertices under the model surface are select-able but the body doesn't hide until I turn the sub-surf modifier off with the View port off button in the modifiers. The vertices I am working on were created off a surface using Duplicate but are not their own Object. I was trying to keep the sub-surf modifier on while working on the duplicated area. Pictures and replication as follows:

[image]
Sub-surf mod on, nothing hidden

[image]
Sub-surf mod on, cube hidden and still visible? but only duplicated face select-able

[image]
Sub-surf mod off in view port, cube still hidden no longer visible but face loses modifier

Replication steps:

1. New project cube
2. Enter Edit Mode
3. Duplicate (Shift+D) top face of cube of cube and place a small distance over cube
4. Apply the subdivision-surface modifier
5. Verify modifier boxes are selected (cage, viewport, etc)
6. Select all faces of cube and Hide (H)
7. The cube is still visible and no vertices/edges/faces are select-able, except the face that was duplicated.
8. Click the View port button on the sub-surf modifier and the cube disappears but now the duplicated face no longer has the modifier.

Is this a bug or as designed?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. Please report it on Blender's bug tracker or let me know and I'll create a ticket for you.

Comment: Yes please do. This is an issue with GPU sub-surf turned on in preferences.

Comment: I was informed by Philipp Oeser that this was already report in https://developer.blender.org/T96080

Comment: Ok, thank you again for reporting the bug. Looks like it’s been elevated to get solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing exactly the steps you provided. When I tried doing step 6 (selecting the face of the cube and pressing H to hide it), this is where our outputs differ. In my case, the cube is no longer visible. This led me to think that our settings might be different so I tweaked here and there and found that your GPU subdivision might be turned on. You can turn it off by:

edit > preferences > viewport > Subdivision > Uncheck GPU subdivision

This might do the trick.

I can't explain why the GPU subdivision does this because I don't know anything about the backend side of blender but turning it off might give you the output you expect.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Turning the GPU subdivision off allows the cube to hide now.